# Using tikz, or something like it, to make custom arrows for tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I would like to define an arrow in latex that looks like an arrow with a circle around it.  Something like:

[image]

The size of the circle is irrelevant.  In text, I have been using

```
\newcommand{\arrcirc}{\longrightarrow \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \circ ~~}
```

It works fine most of the time, but it does not work in tikz-cd.

Is there a way to define a special kind of tikz object that can be used as an arrow type in tikz-cd?

Something like

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{tikzcd}
      A \ar[r,"\circ"{description}] & B
\end{tikzcd}
```

sort of works, but leaves an awkward gap around the circle.  If there was a way to move the lines so that they touch the circle, that could be completely acceptable, but I can't seem to find it in the tikz-cd manual.  Perhaps one could use a normal label above the arrow and the circle label down onto the arrow.

Oh, the reason I would like to use this kind of arrow in particular is that it is common in rewriting theory to use such an arrow for "developments"

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, see also my edit for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to you two possible alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=latex}}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow{r}[anchor=center]{\bigcirc} & B\\
        C \arrow{r}[anchor=center, yshift=-.03ex]{\circ} & D\\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  If I may, where did you find the syntax for describing arrows by \arrow{1}[2]{3}?  I am probably blind, but I didn't find it in http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher Look at para. 1.4 Alternative syntax for arrows, page 4.